# How to exclude DBLINK

Tags: python, sql, oracle, sqlite

I have 2 databases on different servers DB1 and DB2. DBlink is created on DB1 for DB2.
I have only 1 table to be used which is present on DB1 for which I have to use dblink otherwise I can directly hit DB2. Is there any way to get exclude DB1 Dblink and have DB1 table data too?
Also, I don't have the right to create anything on DB2.
e.g.
select * from tb1
join tb2
on tb1.col = tb2.col

Instead of going through DB1 where dblink is present for DB2. I want to directly connect DB2 by getting of one table in DB2 or using python sqllite or sqlalchemy

Comment: So you can directly connect to DB1 and can use a DB Link from DB1 to DB2. Where is the problem? You can connect to DB1 and use query such as `select * from tb1 join tb2@DB2 on tb1.col = tb2.col` (Assuming `tb1`is on DB1 and `tb2` on DB2)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to get exclude DB1 Dblink and have DB1 table data too?

No, there's not. Especially as you can't create anything on DB2 where all other tables reside. You *have to* access DB1, and the only way - as they are in different **databases** - is to use a database link.

**However**! Some people say "database" while - in Oracle - it is a "schema" (which resides in the same database). I'd say that you don't have that "problem", i.e. that you know which is which. Though, if you don't then: if they are really just two different schemas in the same database, then you don't need a database link and can access DB1 data by other means (DB1 grants you `select` privilege; then reference its table by preceding its name with the owner name).

Comment: No, it's  2 different databases but yes both are oracle DBs.

Comment: Then it is a database link, no other way. If you could create objects in DB2, you'd create a **materialized view** (which can be indexed) and use it in your query, which would probably make things way faster.